# Initramfs unpacking failed: decoding failed on 2010 macbook after changing wifi drivers

Tags: boot, macbook, moklistrt

i installed linux on a 2010 macbook, as a project to help renew my grandma's old macbook. Every time it started it gave me `failed to set moklistrt` but said  `continuing boot since secure mode is disabled` but i tried to switch some driver stuff for wifi, and now it takes forever to get past the MoklistRT error, then proceeds to give me `Initramfs unpacking failed: decoding failed.`. please help